# How to generate unique rsa key pair (2048) using 'AndroidKeyStore' provider?

Tags: android, rsa

I have this code in my Android app for generating RSA KeyPair. This code generates same keypair on Android 8 on some devices. Devices include Lenovo K8, Nokia 3 .

Only on these devices the keypair generated is same across same models. 
If I do not use AndroidKeyStore Provider and use BouncyCastle instead, the keys are unique. But I want to use the android provider and still have unique keys generated.

```
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = null;
try {

    keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");

    KeyGenParameterSpec spec = new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("somealias", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN)
        .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256)
        .setKeySize(2048)
        .build();
    keyPairGenerator.initialize(spec);

} catch(Exception e) {
    throw new KeyStoreException(e);
}

KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

byte[] encodedP = publicKey.getEncoded();
```

Need to get unique keys every time, and on all devices.

The Base64 encoded values of encodeP with two consecutive runs using this line of code:
String basePub = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encodedP);

RUN #1

MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA9RmCTb9FJG8rS9ldKiLQsQ7wNtKMvr8aLB+5V7VlNxKkL14ZE+gBMbsHg0QNEL7SL+UiorDeHT5gMg1pHQrq/dJY8WehjXmOsjol8DZaX0qsOLKAqCP0mYK90OjbyZOoGNs7qq7crtSv+oF8aDFzUcTbx/SghEQM9ZjGXSgckpPUsMX3zzf3cZvwZPbTG6y9qAR43nlEAIRaeAPtz8hh/FunW5UeXajsHpyoD9im4HRgm3OzoZYdHXd6kSy1eCmqNJ4DzVmq9EVpX5YTBb3RqeADk7pVGck+eJK4d91Vk5cdsykX6ITCfQwFi1duywHkAZjIG6lXxsTW1HoC96qIfwIDAQAB

RUN#2

MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA9RmCTb9FJG8rS9ldKiLQsQ7wNtKMvr8aLB+5V7VlNxKkL14ZE+gBMbsHg0QNEL7SL+UiorDeHT5gMg1pHQrq/dJY8WehjXmOsjol8DZaX0qsOLKAqCP0mYK90OjbyZOoGNs7qq7crtSv+oF8aDFzUcTbx/SghEQM9ZjGXSgckpPUsMX3zzf3cZvwZPbTG6y9qAR43nlEAIRaeAPtz8hh/FunW5UeXajsHpyoD9im4HRgm3OzoZYdHXd6kSy1eCmqNJ4DzVmq9EVpX5YTBb3RqeADk7pVGck+eJK4d91Vk5cdsykX6ITCfQwFi1duywHkAZjIG6lXxsTW1HoC96qIfwIDAQAB

Comment: That code will never generate the same key pair. You are mistaken.

Comment: It does on Lenovo K8 Android 8.

Comment: Prove it. Post the base64 encoding of  `encodedP` from two consecutive runs.

Comment: To make sure the values are well verified, I compared them on https://www.diffchecker.com/diff

Comment: If true this is an almost unbelievable security flaw. I'm still skeptical without an independent confirmation. Note that, when I run your code on an Android 8 (API 26) emulator, I get different results every time.

Comment: You are right James, I too get unique values on emulator. Exception are these few devices like Lenovo K8/K8+, Nokia 3 etc.  When I tested on Lenovo K8+ with Android 7 did not have this issue.

Comment: This may or may not be an Android-specific problem. In any event you can report Android bugs [here](https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/report-bugs) and Lenovo bugs [here](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/product-security/reporting-a-vulnerability). I would make the same report to both, and note in the report that you are sending the report to both places.

Comment: Needless to say, please update this question with any progress reports and information about a resolution.

Comment: There has been no progress in both forums on this issue.

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135217121

Comment: Ok, well, you did everything you could. Thank you.